# Anaconda-Python RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.22) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am getting a warning that doesn't seem to be covered in any other online resource. I have Anaconda Python 3.6 installed. The warning I get when I create a new Conda environment is:

```
RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.22) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
```

I thought it was a pip issue because of a possibly related question (not sure if it actually is: [How to fix urllib3 RuntimeError: Requests dependency 'urllib3' must be version >= 1.21.1, < 1.22?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397101/how-to-fix-urllib3-runtimeerror-requests-dependency-urllib3-must-be-version)). But I get the same issue:

```
 $ conda update pip
/Users/VincentLa/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.22) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
```

Comment: Note for anyone else coming across this thread. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda.

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with Anaconda because it is happening on other systems without Anaconda.

Answer (score 15):

```
pip install --upgrade chardet
```

may help.

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: (I also had to do `pip install --upgrade urllib3`) but this worked!

Comment: Worked for me in python 3.7

Answer (score 12):

The only combination that helped me was (taken from http://blog.51cto.com/binuu/1948043):

```
pip uninstall urllib3    
pip uninstall chardet
pip install requests
```

All other ones were unable to update `chardet`, as "it was already updated" (it appears, that info was taken for that lib in another location).

Comment: Didn't worked until I added --no-cache-dir option to pip install requests

Comment: Had to do it from within an environment.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue.

The cause is from your python instance being confused about multiple libraries with different versions in different locations.

This Ubuntu scenario that i had will also yield your error.

a) Ubuntu Python libraries installed via `sudo apt-get install python3-requests` will download source to `/usr/lib/python*/dist-packages`

b) Ubuntu Python libraries installed via `sudo -H pip3 install requests` will download source to `/usr/local/lib/python*/dist-packages`

c) OS PATH & PYTHON_PATH point to `/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib`

d) You get a runtime warning because of python's library selection precedence. It therefore warns you that your current library in `/usr/local/lib` is incompatible with the dependancy located in the parent os library location `/usr/lib`

For your specific scenario, it seems you are using MacOS which has - python installed out of the box, and a custom python installation via anaconda.

To prevent conflict i recommend you remove the os python path /usr/lib/python when starting anaconda's python instance.

This will make sure it only uses anaconda's python libraries only, and not from your os.

Comment: Can you outline the steps to remove the os python path /usr/lib/python when starting anaconda's python instance?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

```
pip uninstall requests
pip install requests
pip uninstall docopt # maybe would not be installed.
pip install docopt # install it nonetheless.
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me:

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```