# How to prevent conda virtual env pip from using Python 2.7 system libraries?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I have a fresh install of Anaconda 4.5.10 (Python 3.6 64-bit version) on Ubuntu 16.04. I created a Python 2.7 conda env called `py2.7` using the following command:

`conda create -n py2.7 python=2.7`

After activating the environment `which pip` returns `/home/sam/anaconda3/envs/py2.7/bin/pip`. When I try to install anything with pip I get a dependency error. For example:

```
(py2.7) sam@sam-M3:~$ pip install numpy
/home/sam/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.22) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sam/anaconda3/envs/py2.7/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip.commands import get_summaries, get_similar_commands
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/completion.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pip.basecommand import Command
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip.req import InstallRequirement, parse_requirements
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.markers import interpret as markers_interpret
  File "/home/sam/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distlib/markers.py", line 108, in <module>
    DEFAULT_CONTEXT = default_context()
  File "/home/sam/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distlib/markers.py", line 97, in default_context
    'platform_python_implementation': platform.python_implementation(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 1481, in python_implementation
    return _sys_version()[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 1443, in _sys_version
    repr(sys_version))
ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 23:32:55) \n[GCC 7.2.0]'
```

I can see that the error is being caused by Python trying to access libraries in `/usr/lib/python2.7`, but I want to only access libraries that are part of the conda py2.7 env. My issue is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672866/10274139, but the solution isn't clear. With the conda env activated, when I list my environmental variables, I see nothing about other Python paths:

```
(py2.7) sam@sam-M3:~$ env | grep python
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/sam/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Also, if I create a Python 3.7 conda env, I get no errors when I `pip install` in that env.

Comment: I think you can add this to your virtualenv bin/activate file:
`export PYTHONPATH="/the/correct/path"`

Comment: After activating the conda evn, I tried `export PYTHONPATH="/home/sam/anaconda3/envs/py3.6/lib"` but I got the same error. Also note that `echo $PYTHONPATH` was empty before I set it, and this post claims that `PYTHONPATH` isn't used by Anaconda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31841132/10274139

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate the problem. I did not encounter any errors. I am using conda version 4.5.10 (Python 3.6 64-bit version) on Ubuntu 18.04.

I ran the following commands to create my environment and install using pip.

```
conda create --name Test2 python=2.7
source activate Test2
pip install numpy
```

If you ran something similar, try updating conda and see if that helps.

To update conda :

```
conda update conda
```

Comment: Also consider adding the statements you used to create the environment in the question.